# MySQL column of occurrences of the primary key in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have two tables that are already being used. I will simplify them for this use case.

Table Collections

```
--------------------------------------------
| collectionID | collectionName | vendorID |
-----PK------------------------------FK-----
```

Table items

```
------------------------------------
| itemID | vendorID | collectionID |
----PK-------FK-----------FK--------
```

Many items can have the same collectionID. collectionID cannot be null.

I want to create a new column in collections:

```
"ALTER TABLE `collections` ADD `occurs` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;"
```

that has a value equal to that of how many times its Primary Key is referenced (its default would be 0 as a collection needs to exist before an item can be put into it).

I also want this new column to update as new items are input. Is there a simple way to create this column and rule (I'm assuming that to have it update, I will need a trigger or something similar, but I am not positive on this to be honest as I want this new column in collections to get updated in response to items being INSERTed upon)

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Unless your data is quite large, just calculate this on-the-fly using a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible in any database i know .... your only 2 options are:

- calculate every time needed
- use "on-insert-triggers" (dangerous, unexpected locking might occur)

or "materialized view" could be used, if adhoc-calculation is no option:
[MySql materialized view](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views)